# show / hide images depending on value from drop menu

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need a drop menu, this drop menu will be a numerical value and I want to show only a certain amout of images depending on this value.

Could anyone help please.

```
<div>
            <select id="selectLevel" style="width:8%" onChange="changeOPLevel()">
                <option value="1" selected=""> Level 1</option>
                <option value="2"> Level 2</option>
                <option value="3"> Level 3</option>
                <option value="4"> Level 4</option>
                <option value="5"> Level 5</option>
                <option value="6"> Level 6</option>
            </select>

</div>
```

The image is

```
<img src="buildings/lvl 4.png">
```

now , the scenario will be if level 5 is selected there will be 14 pictures (all the same image) and 16 images if level 6 is selected. If someone can help on these two, i shold be able to modify it to do all that i need.

Thanks in advance,

wayne

Comment: And how are you calculating the number of images to be shown with value of dropdown?

Comment: i know how many images i want per lvl, but i dont know how to display them lvl 1 will be 6 images rising by 2 images per lvl

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 16 images, and you'd like to show a number *N* of them based on a selected level *L*, where N = 2L + 4.

You can do this with a couple lines of jQuery:

```
var n = $('#selectLevel').val()*2+4;
$('img').show().eq(n-1).nextAll().hide();
```

The first line determines the number of images to show.

The second line does five things:

1. `$('img')`:  This selects all images on the page as a collection.
2. `.show()`:  This shows all those images.
3. `.eq(n-1)`:  This grabs the n<sup>th</sup> image.  (In JavaScript, collections are zero-based, so we have to subtract 1 from `n`.)
4. `.nextAll()`:  This selects all the following siblings of the image found in step 3.
5. `.hide()`:  This hides all the siblings selected in step 4.

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/v44LwLhr/1/**

Comment: ty for you info, i managed to get some other info and used NG repeat and an array